# Issue in Drupal Dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, view, drupal-7

I download a code of dashboard in codepen: `https://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/pNRQxK`, but i need this in drupal, so I make the respective changes but I have this issue(the site work but show this issue):

```
tb-megamenu-frontend.js?ovwzqg:28 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).once is not a function
    at Object.attach (tb-megamenu-frontend.js?ovwzqg:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (drupal.js?ovwzqg:76)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?ovwzqg:74)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (drupal.js?ovwzqg:557)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
```

image: https://screencast.com/t/DgeQN3SQA

Comment: How is this going Javier?

Answer (score 0):

The console error is explaining that on line 28 that you are calling a function that is undefined - 'once'.

I suspect you have some of your own JavaScript not from the CodePen, as that JS doesn't make use of 'once' that I can see. A good reason to include the source code that is being run when you can.

'Once' is not default jQuery, it is a 'plugin'/'extension':

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-once

So my recommendation is:

- Determine whether you need 'once'

  - (I.e. [Would 'one' not suffice?](http://api.jquery.com/one/))
- If 'once' is needed, you will need to include the JS file

  - Drupal has myriad ways of including JS

    - .info file in a module

      - Included on every page.
    - Attach to a specific form ($form['#attached']['js'])

      - Included on a specific form.
    - External link to JS/CDN

      - Can be done in many ways, template file inline html, drupal_add_js
        Drupal

Let me know how you go. Can provide more information re; Drupal JS if needed.